# C++ function wont work

Tags: c++, function

I need to calculate the variance and standard deviation for 15 numbers read. I am not sure why but the function wont execute, the console just blinks. Could someone please explain what the issue is, thanks.

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

void stats(int array[], double& var, double& sd);

int main ()
{
int array[15];
double var = 0, sd = 0;
cout << "Please enter 15 numbers to calculate var and SD\n";
for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter number: ";
    cin >> array[i];
}

stats(array,var,sd);

cout << "Numbers entered are: ";
for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    cout << array[i] << " ";
}

cout << "Variance is: " << var << endl;
cout << "Standard deviation is: " << sd << endl;
}
```

Function definition

```
void stats(int array[],double& var, double& sd)
{
int sum = 0;
double sum2 = 0;
double mean = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{sum = sum + array[i];
}

mean = sum/15;

for(int i = 0; i < 15;)
{sum2 = pow((array[i]-mean),2) + sum2;
}

var = sum2/15;
sd = pow(var,0.5);}
```

Comment: How far does the code get? Do you get to the lines where you try and input 15 numbers? Can you not type the numbers in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 15;)
{sum2 = pow((array[i]-mean),2) + sum2;
}
```

That loop never increments `i` so it runs forever. You missed an `i++` there, so it should begin like

```
for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some remarks that might help improve your style:

- if you want to get rid of the hardcoded 15, use a vector instead of an array and `push_back` whatever comes from `cin`
- even though for ints it doesn't make any difference, better `++i` than `i++` (for iterators it might make a difference in terms of performance)
- you can sum all the elements of a vector using `std::accumulate`
- `pow` is slightly inefficient to raise something to the power of 2, better just multiply the number times itself
- `main` should return 0